# Facebook like status input

Tags: facebook, html, contenteditable, word-wrap, overlap

Is there a ready similar input like the status input in Facebook?
I mean, they use a contenteditable div, and they've wrapped it all pretty good. They can resize it (on focus/blur), an it continues word-wrapping and expanding, and when you type a really long word in their input, which can't be wrapped, it stays inside the div and doesn't overlap other elements near it..

Please help me doing those two things on a contenteditable div, or if you know of a ready one, please share.

Thanks.

P.S. I did try doing it myself an not just being lazy. I almost succeeded in stopping the overlap, but didn't manage to make the div stay contenteditable(word-wrap, expandable) after a  height resize. I also thought of trying to understand how Facebook do it by myself, but it's pretty hard for a newbie to understand their code as it's all minified and gzipped and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They (Facebook) seem to be using this CSS

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: Thanks! but what about the resizing problem? (which occurs in opera and chrome/safari)